# Split Image as Rows x Columns equal sized Image Matrix Using C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, split, image-scaling

> how to split an image into Equal Size `3x3,3x4,4x4,6x6,4x6,6x8` something like that

Conceptualize by given Image: Convert simple image into that form,
[image]

In Given Answer It is General Purpose algorithm to Split an Image into proper scaled **Rows x Columns Equal sized Image Matrix** It Gives out put Like

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I Used Following Code ....But It Doesn't worked perfectally

Load Button Code: **Load The Image into Variable image1**

```
Image image1;
private void btn_Open_File_BG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        image1 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Process Button Code:**Split Picture & Save or Use**

```
private void Img_BG_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rows = 5;//No of Rows as per Desire
            int columns = 6;//No of columns as per Desire
            var imgarray = new Image[rows, columns];//Create Image Array of Size Rows X Colums
            var img = image1;//Get Image from anywhere, From File Or Using Dialogbox used previously
            int height = img.Height;
            int width = img.Width;//Get image Height & Width of Input Image
            int one_img_h = height / rows;
            int one_img_w = width / columns;//You need Rows x Columns, So get 1/rows Height, 1/columns width of original Image
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    imgarray[i, j] = new Bitmap(one_img_w, one_img_h);//generating new bitmap
                    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[i, j]);
                    graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, one_img_w, one_img_h), new Rectangle(i * one_img_w, j * one_img_h, one_img_w, one_img_h), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);//Generating Splitted Pieces of Image
                    graphics.Dispose();
                }
            }
//Image Is spitted You can use it by getting image from **imgarray[Rows, Columns]**
//Or You can Save it by using Following Code


            var destinationFolderName = "";//Define a saving path
            FolderBrowserDialog FolderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();//Get folder Path Where splitted Image Saved
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                destinationFolderName = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        imgarray[i, j].Save(@"" + destinationFolderName + "/Image_" + i + "_" + j + ".jpg");//Save every image in Array [row][column] on local Path
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load Button Code: **Load The Image into Variable image1**

```
Image image1;
private void btn_Open_File_BG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        image1 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Process Button Code:**Split Picture & Save or Use**

```
private void Img_BG_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rows = 5;//No of Rows as per Desire
            int columns = 6;//No of columns as per Desire
            var imgarray = new Image[rows, columns];//Create Image Array of Size Rows X Colums
            var img = image1;//Get Image from anywhere, From File Or Using Dialogbox used previously
            int height = img.Height;
            int width = img.Width;//Get image Height & Width of Input Image
            int one_img_h = height / rows;
            int one_img_w = width / columns;//You need Rows x Columns, So get 1/rows Height, 1/columns width of original Image
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    imgarray[i, j] = new Bitmap(one_img_w, one_img_h);//generating new bitmap
                    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[i, j]);
                    graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, one_img_w, one_img_h), new Rectangle(j * one_img_w, i * one_img_h, one_img_w, one_img_h), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);//Generating Splitted Pieces of Image
                    graphics.Dispose();
                }
            }
//Image Is spitted You can use it by getting image from **imgarray[Rows, Columns]**
//Or You can Save it by using Following Code


            var destinationFolderName = "";//Define a saving path
            FolderBrowserDialog FolderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();//Get folder Path Where splitted Image Saved
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                destinationFolderName = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        imgarray[i, j].Save(@"" + destinationFolderName + "/Image_" + i + "_" + j + ".jpg");//Save every image in Array [row][column] on local Path
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I think you use inadvertently "`j * one_img_w, i * one_img_h`" in **Rectangle**

SO it convert rows into columns and columns into rows